# How to send python error message to teams form Jenkins office 365 connector webbook?

Tags: python, jenkins, office365, microsoft-teams, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to send a python error message in a teams alerts channel, for example:

```
File "Myfile/......../test.py". line 8 n = len(arr_)e SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using different exitcodes depending on if the code throws an exception or fails, so I want to get an alert every time exitcode is not zero, the pipeline with the following code:

```
def runPythonScript(){
    def command =  "Myfile/......../test.py
    def output = sh(
        script: command,
        returnStatus: true,
  
       
        )
    if (output!= 0){
        error "exit code ${output}"
   
       
    }
   
   
       }

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Run test') {
            steps {
                script{
                    try{
                        def pythonOutput = runPythonScript()
               
                   
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                       
                        office365ConnectorSend webhookUrl: 'https://Mywebhook........',
                        message:"started ${env.JOB_NAME} ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)",
                        status: 'FAILURE',
                        color: '#00ff00'",
                        factDefinitions:[
                        [ name: "Commit Message", template: "${e}"],
                        [ name: "Pipeline Duration", template: "time example"],
                        [ name: "Current build result", template: "${currentBuild.currentResult}"]
                        ]

                        throw e
                       
                       
                    }
                   
                }
               
               
               
           
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

The code works and sends the alert to the right channel with the desired exit code, I just want to include the error message, as explained above, also if you could recommend any documentation related would be great, so far I have found only very easy examples. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to write the error to a file from the Python program and then read that in the catch block and add to the message.